# Why not change my background and title after accelerometer data is recieved? SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

print and func call is successful both time, but my background and title change only when i restart my app and works only 1 times. Here is my code:

```
    var motionManager = CMMotionManager()

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    startMotionManager()
}

func startMotionManager() {

    if motionManager.accelerometerAvailable {
    motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.2
    motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue(), withHandler: {
        [weak self] (data, error) in

        print(data!.acceleration.z)

        if(data!.acceleration.z > 0.8) {
            self!.win()
            print("Win")
        }

        if (data!.acceleration.z < -0.9){
            self!.pass()
            print("Pass")
        }
        return
        })
    }

}

func pass() {
    print("passfunction")
    self.testLabel.text = "PASS"
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
}

func win() {
    testLabel.text = "WIN"
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
}
```

}

My main goal is call func Win when acceleration.z > 0.8 which change the title label to "Win" and view background to green
If acceleration.z < -0.9 then call Pass function which change my background to red and etc...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ensure, that UIKit methods will be called from the main thread!

Answer (score 1):

I tired all day solve this. After I posted my question I found the problem in my code.

```
    func pass() {
       NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {

       self.testLabel.text = "PASS"
       self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
       }
    }
```

Comment: That's right - always call UIKit methods on the main thread But usually, using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { ... }` is shorter.